# can't display variable inside protected class

Tags: c++

Can't access variable "`shipcost`" when trying to print it out. I either get 0.00 or the address in hexadecimal. Not sure why this is happening, I've declared it inside protected in the main class `Package` and then again specifically as `4.99` in the private `Video Games` sub-class. In other sub-classes they're different...that I should note, and is the whole reason it's protected. So 4.99 is not a constant.

But do note that it returns the correct dollar amount when used inside a calculation for cost and total cost. So it's being used properly but I try to use "cout << shipcost << endl;" inside the class Package, it fails to output anything but 0.00. And that's my problem.

```
class Package
{
protected:
    string name_and_address = "?";

    double cost = 0.0;
    double discount = 0.0;
    double discount_rate = 0.0;

    bool overnight_delivery = false;
    bool insured = false;

    string package_contents = "?";

    double shipcost = 0.0;

};

class Video_Games :public Package
{
private:
    int num_games = 0;
    double shipcost = 4.99; 

public:
    Video_Games(string location, int number_of_games, bool express, bool insurance)
    {
        num_games = number_of_games;
        name_and_address = location;
        overnight_delivery = express;
        insured = insurance;

        package_contents = to_string(num_games) + " Video Game(s)";

        cost = calculate_cost();
        discount = calculate_discount();

    }

    ~Video_Games() {};

protected:

    double calculate_cost()
    {
        cost = num_games * 19.99;
        if (overnight_delivery) { cost += shipcost; }
        if (insured) { cost *= 1.06; }

        return cost;
    }
};
```

Comment: *"So it's being used properly..."* - well, actually it's not. You can't "override" values of member variables like that in C++. Either initialize the member variable in your constructor using a parameter, or make a virtual member function that returns the shipping cost.

Comment: It looks like you have "shipcost" in both your base class and your derived class.  That's going to make you have a bad day.

Comment: lol @ DiB...thank you for clarifying that. I had a hunch that having shipcost not return anything was going to be a headache.

Comment: not sure how to create a virtual function that differentiates based off of a derived class identifier. so i think i'll just stick with the variable using a parameter for each derived class.

Comment: Greg can you say what you said using simpler terminology? I'm having trouble understanding what that would mean re: my code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're trying to access the variable,but a simple public function will print the correct value:

```
class Video_Games :public Package
{
private:
    int num_games = 0;
    double shipcost = 4.99;

public:
    Video_Games( string location , int number_of_games , bool express , bool insurance )
    {
        num_games = number_of_games;
        name_and_address = location;
        overnight_delivery = express;
        insured = insurance;

        package_contents = to_string( num_games ) + " Video Game(s)";

        cost = calculate_cost();
        //discount = calculate_discount();

    }

    ~Video_Games() {};
    void PrintVars( ostream& out )
    {
        out << num_games << '\t' << shipcost << '\n';
    }
protected:

    double calculate_cost()
    {
        cost = num_games * 19.99;
        if ( overnight_delivery ) {
            cost += shipcost;
        }
        if ( insured ) {
            cost *= 1.06;
        }

        return cost;
    }
};


Video_Games vg("abcde",10,true,true);

vg.PrintVars( cout );
```

I'm still not sure if I got it.  It looks to me that setting the value of shipcost instead of declaring a new one, will allow each derived class to access their own value:

```
class Package
{
protected:
    string name_and_address = "?";

    double cost = 0.0;
    double discount = 0.0;
    double discount_rate = 0.0;

    bool overnight_delivery = false;
    bool insured = false;

    string package_contents = "?";

    double shipcost = 0.0;
    void PrintVars( ostream& out )
    {
        cout << "Cost = " << cost << '\n'
            << "Discount = " << discount << '\n'
            << "Discount Rate = " << discount_rate << '\n'
            << "Ship Cost = " << shipcost << '\n';

    }

};
class Video_Games :public Package
{
private:
    int num_games = 0;

public:
    Video_Games( string location , int number_of_games , bool express , bool insurance )
    {
        shipcost = 4.99;
        num_games = number_of_games;
        name_and_address = location;
        overnight_delivery = express;
        insured = insurance;

        package_contents = to_string( num_games ) + " Video Game(s)";

        cost = calculate_cost();
        //discount = calculate_discount();

    }

    ~Video_Games() {};
    void Print( ostream& out )
    {
        PrintVars( out );
    }
protected:

    double calculate_cost()
    {
        cost = num_games * 19.99;
        if ( overnight_delivery ) {
            cost += shipcost;
        }
        if ( insured ) {
            cost *= 1.06;
        }

        return cost;
    }
};
class Board_Games :public Package
{
private:
    int num_games = 0;
public:
    Board_Games( string location , int number_of_games , bool express , bool insurance )
    {
        shipcost = 3.99;
        num_games = number_of_games;
        name_and_address = location;
        overnight_delivery = express;
        insured = insurance;

        package_contents = to_string( num_games ) + " Video Game(s)";

        cost = calculate_cost();
        //discount = calculate_discount();

    }

    ~Board_Games() {};
    void Print( ostream& out )
    {
        PrintVars( out );
    }
protected:

    double calculate_cost()
    {
        cost = num_games * 19.99;
        if ( overnight_delivery ) {
            cost += shipcost;
        }
        if ( insured ) {
            cost *= 1.06;
        }

        return cost;
    }
};

Video_Games vg("abcde",10,true,true);   
vg.Print( cout );
cout << '\n';
Board_Games bg( "cdefg" , 20 , false , false );
bg.Print( cout );
```

This yields this return:

```
Cost = 217.183
Discount = 0
Discount Rate = 0
Ship Cost = 4.99

Cost = 399.8
Discount = 0
Discount Rate = 0
Ship Cost = 3.99
```

Comment: I can print the value, that's not a problem. I'm trying to create a variable that's responsive to the class that's being used. So if I use "shipcost" as a variable inside the Package class it should be responsive to every subclass, and change to the appropriate cost as necessary. So for Video Games it would be 4.99, for Phones it would be 9.99, etc. etc. In the same way that my "cost" is not just a singular "cost" it's a variable that depends on the input. I'm having trouble bridging this gap between constant numbers passing through a variable and numbers passed through a parameter in the main

Comment: I'm trying to print it along with all the other data inside the Package class that's at the top. It's the big class that holds all the other classes.

Comment: @polymorphism - I added more code for you to look at.

Answer (score -1):

You did not ask a question. However, because you state:

> "Not sure why this is happening"

as well as,

> "I try to use `cout << shipcost << endl;`" inside the `class Package`, it fails to output anything but `0.00`. And that's my problem"

I must interpret your intended question to be:

Why will the following code not output the value `4.99` when I add `"cout << shipcost << endl;"` inside the `class Package`?

I see at least one possibility:
The value of `4.99` is in `class Video_Games`.
Try adding `"cout << shipcost << endl;"` inside the `class Video_Games` instead of placing this statement inside of `class Package`.
Also, you are declaring shipcost twice by using the word `"double"` twice.
Try using a setter function in `class Video_Games` (delete "double")